# QuickBlox Opponent Video and audio stream is not coming?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox SDk for video calling. When i call from one user to another, I received the call from that user but opponent video and voice stream is not received? Can you please suggest me how can i resolve this problem. Even when I am trying Quickblox's demo app, then also I am getting same issue. Every delegate method is getting called. no error is coming up but stream is not working. Please help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want me to show the code?

Comment: What version of sdk do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
let opponentVideoTrack = QBRTCRemoteVideoView(frame: someFrame)
view.insertSubview(self.opponentVideoTrack)
```

Do following in receivedRemoteVideoTrack delegate method

```
func session(session: QBRTCSession!, receivedRemoteVideoTrack videoTrack: QBRTCVideoTrack!, fromUser userID: NSNumber!) {
    self.callStatus.text = "Getting Video Call "      
    self.opponentVideoTrack!.setVideoTrack(videoTrack)
}
```

And don't forget to add QBRTCCameraCapture object in initializedLocalMediaStream delegate method like below example

```
func session(session: QBRTCSession!, initializedLocalMediaStream mediaStream: QBRTCMediaStream!) {
    self.currentSession!.localMediaStream.videoTrack.videoCapture = self.myVideoCapture
}
```

where self.myVideoCapture is instance of QBRTCCameraCapture.

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue

**Solution**

I have implemented this below line in receivedRemoteVideoTrack delegate method

```
func session(session: QBRTCSession!, receivedRemoteVideoTrack videoTrack: QBRTCVideoTrack!, fromUser userID: NSNumber!) {
   //solve issue by this line
   self.session!.localMediaStream.videoTrack.videoCapture = self.videoCapture
   self.opponentVideoView?.setVideoTrack(videoTrack) 
}
```

refrence :- https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios